# How to know the exact result in Paillier cheaper-constant multiplication

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, paillier

The encryption function $E_{k^+}: Z_n \rightarrow Z_{n^2}$.
The decryption function $D_{k^-}: Z_{n^2} \rightarrow Z_n$.
$m_1 = 42, k = 15, n=77$.
After encryption, exponentiation and decryption, I get:
$$D_{k^-}((E_{k^+}(m_1))^k) \equiv 14 \bmod 77$$
The class of residue of $14$ is of the form:
$$\langle 14 \rangle = \{\alpha \in Z: 14 + \alpha*77\}$$
And one of these values is $630 = 14 + 8*77 \equiv 630 \bmod 5929 \equiv 42*15 \bmod 77$
So, the question is after I decrypt and get $14$ how can I, from this value, deduce that the real value of $\alpha$ I am searching for is $8$, and from that deduce $630$, the real value of the product?
Cause, as far as I know, all possible numbers modulo $5929$ in $\langle 14 \rangle$ could be valid products if I don't know $m_1$ and $k$.

Comment: Hint: 42×15 ≥ 77

Comment: Yeah, I know. You trying to say that if the product is greater than the modulo then I can't get the true result in anyway?

Comment: Yes. Pailler computes modulo $n$ even if the cryptograms are in $[0,n^2)$. Not coincidentally, $42\times15\equiv14\pmod{77}$. For Pailler to be secure, you need $n$ of several hundred digits, so that's not necessarily an issue.

Comment: Ah yeah I have lost myself in the examples and totally forgot that I have to think them with a very big modulo. Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you write your example and close this question?

Answer (score 1):

> Are you trying to say that if the product is greater than the modulo then I can't get the true result in anyway?

Yes. Pailler computes modulo $n$ even if the cryptograms are in $[0,n^2)$. Not coincidentally, $42\times15\equiv14\pmod{77}$. For Pailler to be secure, one needs $n$ of several hundred digits, so that's not necessarily an issue.